# How to connect VB.Net to Excel as Database Connection?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I need a database connection using microsoft excel but i don't know what codes i should
use. I can only do a connection between access and VB but in excel I can't

I copied this in the net but it doesn't work on me

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    'Fill the [Excel file fullpath] with specific value
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
    ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= E:\DATABASE\VBtoExcel\VBtoExcel\bin\DataBaseExcel.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
        ("select * from [Sheet1]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Dont forget about your excel DB connection ... `cnXLS = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=test.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")` ... for xls 2003 ..

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to select from a sheet of an Excel file requires the $ character at the end of the sheet name.

```
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

A tip, [add the Import Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) for the System.Data.OleDb to your file. So you could type shorter names

```
MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand


    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        cn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source =O:\design\Connect to Excel\Agent.xls;extended properties=excel 8.0;"
        cn.Open()

        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [Data Agent$]values('" & TxtId.Text & "','" & TxtName.Text & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox("Sucessfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)


    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
        ' Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```